# Symfony: image_tag() can you change the directory?

Tags: php, symfony1

When using the `image_tag()` method like this:

```
<?php echo image_tag('whatever.png') ?>
```

Symfony outputs an image like this:

```
<img src="/images/whatever.png"/>
```

By default it uses `images` as the base images folder in your web directory. Can you change this default folder name in the Symfony config? Say I wanted to use `img` instead of `images`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config variable is named `sf_web_images_dir_name`. You can see that in the source [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/helper/AssetHelper.php). It can be set via `sfConfig::set` or through `app.yml`.

All told, it seems like the easiest way to do this is adding:

```
<?php sfConfig::set('sf_web_images_dir_name', 'img'); ?>
```

to the end of app.yml, simply because that is where config stuff is expected, but there are a variety of different ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to configure this globally in a YAML settings file, but this should be easy to do in `apps/frontend/config/frontendConfiguration.class.php` (or the equivalent for your application name), using `sfConfig::set`:

```
<?php

class frontendConfiguration extends sfApplicationConfiguration
{
  public function configure()
  {
     sfConfig::set('sf_web_images_dir_name', 'img');
  }
}
```